# How do I write text to the console without a newline in Fortran?

Tags: io, fortran

I'm writing an interpreter for Brainfuck (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) in Fortran and I need a way to write a character to the console without also adding a newline. Because it's Brainfuck, I can't assemble the characters into a string that is printed after the program has finished.

I have tried something along the lines of:

```
WRITE(*, "(A)") characterToPrint
```

But the console only shows the first character that is printed (e.g. when trying to interpret a Hello World program, a single "H" would be visible and nothing else). Interestingly, though, the following works just fine:

```
    WRITE (*, "(A)", advance = "no") 'H'
    WRITE (*, "(A)", advance = "no") 'e'
    WRITE (*, "(A)", advance = "no") 'l'
    ...
```

Is there something about `WRITE` that would cause this that I'm not aware of? What else could be causing this issue?

Comment: How is characterToPrint declared? In Fortran, when declaring the string, you specify the length of the string. I wonder if you only have a length of 1 declared.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. We really need your complete code, see [mcve].

Comment: Just to expand @NicholasBauman 's comment, if you have declared the variable as CHARACTER :: characterToPrint , that is without a length, it will default to length 1 and you will see what you describe here. But until you show a whole program we are guessing as to the correct answer.